# How to test with RSpec a Rails plugin using "link_to" and "current_page?"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, plugins, rspec

I'm writing a Rails plugin that builds up a menu in a view. I'm using `link_to` to build the link and `current_page?` to set `class="active"` on the current page.

I've `include`d `ActionView::Helpers::UrlHelper` so I can use `link_to`.

To get `current_page?` working in the view, I've had to inherit the current class (apparently `ActionView::Base`) and it works perfectly well. Unfortunately, this totally breaks the tests with RSpec.

I'm calling `link_to` and `current_page?` like this:

```
def menu(options = {}, &block)
  carte = my_menu.new(self)
  yield carte
  carte.to_s unless carte.empty?
end

class my_menu
  include ActionView::Helpers::TagHelper
  include ActionView::Helpers::UrlHelper

  def initialize(base)
    @base = base
  end

  def link
    @base.link_to(name, url_options, html_options)
    @base.current_page?(url_options)
  end
end
```

And I get this error with RSpec:
    Undefined method `link_to' for #< Spec::Rails::Example::RailsExampleGroup::Subclass_1:0x24afa90>

Any clue?

Answer (score 8):

```
include ActionView::Helpers::UrlHelper
```

In your Spec should solve the problem.  Or in your spec_helper.rb.  I think this is basically what view specs do by default.